# Extension of Schengen visa, or apply for a new visa?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, visa-extensions

I am travelling to Europe from May 7th to 25th. Below is my itinerary:

- Italy: 7th to 14th May
- Czech Republic: 14th to 18th May
- Belgium : 18th to 21st May
- Netherlands : 21st to 25th May

I have applied for my visa from Italy, and already got it. The issue is the visa duration is from 5th May to 3rd June and the duration of stay is 15 days, which only covers my trip till Belgium, ie 7th to 21st May. It does not cover the remaining 4 days, and the Italian consulate said they cannot extend.

Can I apply for a visa from the Netherlands consulate? Since my duration of stay and validity will be over by the 21st of May? Or because the visa is from the 5th May to 3rd June, will it count as two active visas?

Since the Italian consulate cannot extend, should I apply for a new visa from the Netherlands consulate?

Also, I have taken a sabbatical from work. What kind of papers would I require for the Netherlands?

Comment: Also, the Italian visa that I have got is a multiple entry, I'm not sure if that is relevant to the information provided.

Comment: Did you explain your itinerary when you applied for the visa?

Comment: Did you provide exactly this itinerary when you applied for the visa, which has now been issued or have you changed your planes later?

Comment: The exact itinerary was provided along with the hotel reservations, flight bookings, cover letter stating that exact dates. , But since I'm not working or studying as of now (I am applying to universities for further studies)  the Italian consulate said I am dependant on my parents, and hence they cannot issue the extension of the visa. They asked me to try from the Netherlands consulate. But I'm not sure if that will be two active visas.

Comment: You can still apply for a new visa while holding an active visa. We would like to hear from you if you have already commenced the travel.